# Background Images Not Loading on NGINX Server

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, nginx, server

Using Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04, I want to create a website where I keep all of my resources on the host server.

The problem I run in to is when I try to use my background image. If I set it to pull from a website using

```
url(“example.com/example_image.jpg”)
```

it works perfectly fine, but since I want to have it pull the image from my own local server, if I try to do something like

```
url(“/images/example_image.jpg”)
```

it doesn’t work.

I’ve tried a few different things, but I’m really just trying to learn-by-doing and it doesn’t seem to be working properly. Thanks for the help.

Edit #1: Here's my website code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>INDEX.HTML</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Raleway">
<style>
body,h1 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
body, html {height: 100%}
.bgimg {
    background-image: <img src="../example_image.jpg" alt="EXAMPLE">;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="bgimg w3-display-container w3-animate-opacity w3-text-black">
  <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding-large w3-xlarge">
    LOGO
  </div>
  <div class="w3-display-middle">
    <h1 class="w3-jumbo w3-animate-top">TITLE TEXT</h1>
    <hr class="w3-border-grey" style="margin:auto;width:40%">
    <p class="w3-xlarge w3-center">SUBHEADER</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I take it that the file is in `/var/www/html/images/example_image.jpg`.

Comment: Could you provide your actual HTML / CSS (and file paths)? See how much you can simplify in order that it still shows the problem.

Comment: No, the file is currently in /data/images. Root is also currently set to /data.

Comment: Once I return home I will add the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, taking another look, maybe this is to do with NGINX permissions.

Find the user who is running the application. Usually is `www-data`. There's two ways:

Check `/usr/local/nginx/nginx.conf` for a line containing `user NAME`, where NAME , or run this in a terminal:

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

`ps` gets running process information, `grep` searches that output for a matching line containing a string, specifically one containing `nginx` in our case.

Now, change the file ownership using `chown` for the static resources. For a web server folder located at `/home/nick/website-folder/`:

```
sudo chown -R NAME:NAME /home/nick/website-folder/
```

where NAME is the username from earlier, e.g., for the username `www-data` the command is `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/nick/website-folder/`

This gives the Linux user running the NGINX server application the permissions to access the resources in the website folder. You could narrow this scope down further to just `... website-folder/images` if you want to tighten security up. Try the whole directory first.

Comment: Alright, I ran the ps aux | grea nginx command and I see a whole bunch of www-data worker processes and then 1 master process under root. I didn’t see a nginx.conf file where you said to look, but the one I have doesn’t have anything but server_name. I followed what you said to change permissions for www-data but still no dice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your filepaths aren't relative.

On Ubuntu and Linux generally, paths beginning with a `/` are root directories, I.e., think of `/` as you do `C:/` in Windows. It means this is a very top level directory.

If you want to have a path relative to the current folder, that is denoted in Linux by `./`, where the dot represents the working directory.

For example, if I have a script in `/home/nick/docs/` and it has `url('./images/photo.jpg')` then it's referring to an image located at `/home/nick/docs/images/photo.jpg`.

I'm guessing you have your script in a folder that has a sub directory named `images`. In which case, for an image named `photo.jpg`, you want `url('./images/photo.jpg')`.

Another file path notation is `../`. This stands for one directory above the current directory, I.e., its parent. If we have `url('../images/photo.jpg')` in the same script as the previous example, the path would now resolve to `/home/nick/images/photo.jpg`.

Further reading of your code, an I've noticed this:

```
.bgimg {
  background-image: <img src="../example_image.jpg" alt="EXAMPLE">;
...
```

Here it looks like you've tried to inline the HTML img tag inside CSS - you want the CSS `url` property value instead:

```
.bgimg {
  background-image: url('./images/photo.jpg');
}
```

For using `url('./images/photo.jpg')`, the directory structure for your folder should be:

```
root-folder/
| images/
  | photo.jpg
| index.html
| w3.css
```

Comment: I tried using the “./images/example_image.jpg” and just using “./example_image.jpg” too. Neither of those worked. Then I tried using “../example_image.jpg” which didn’t work either. What I find strange is that I have my “stylesheet” working correctly with w3.css located in my root directory. Why doesn’t the background-image work correctly?

Comment: Just changed it to the url(‘./images/example_image.jpg’); and that didn’t work either. All I get is a white background. My css looks good as does all the other code, but it’s just my image that isn’t populating. :/

Comment: Perhaps I should also mention that I put a copy of example_image.jpg in every possible directory that I could think it would be pulling from and still, none of them work.

Comment: Make sure your directory is structured as outlined in my edit

Comment: Just changed the directory as you suggested. I have my root as /data. In that folder we have /images, w3.css, and index.html. In /images we have example_image.jpg. Restart nginx and still just a blank page.

Comment: See my other answer for another idea

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, finally. After changing the permissions, I looked back at the CSS guide from W3Schools and changed my code to this:

```
.bgimg {
     background-image: url(“images/example_art.jpg”);
```

I don’t know why removing the / at the beginning of the file path changed it, but I appreciate the help.